# Difficult integrals involving trigonometric functions

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometric-integrals

How do you evaluate the following integrals?

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{R^2+2R\cos\theta+1} \mathrm d\theta$$

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{R\cos\theta}{R^2+2R\cos\theta+1} \mathrm d\theta$$

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{R\sin\theta}{R^2+2R\cos\theta+1} \mathrm d\theta$$

Apparently there are three cases: one case for $R>1$, another case for $R<1$, and another case for $R=1$.

For context: I am trying to answer problem 6.3.4 of Arfken & Weber (2005). *Mathematical Methods for Physicists* which is to show that

$$\oint_C \frac{\mathrm dz}{z^2+z}=0$$
in which the contour $C$ is defined as $|z|=R>1$ (without using Cauchy's integral formula or the residue theorem).

Comment: Perhaps you could use partial fractions and evaluate two separate integrals.

Comment: If R is constant then the anti-derivative of third one is $ - (1/2)\ Ln(R^2+2 R Cos x+1)$.

Comment: Couldn't you do $\frac1{z^2 + z} = \frac1z - \frac1{z+1}$?

Comment: @brian yao, if I do that, and try to evaluate the integral using the given contour (circle of radius R>1), I would parametrize using the following: $z = Re^{i\theta}, 0\leq\theta\leq2\pi$. The contour integral would then be $\oint_0^{2\pi} \frac{\mathrm dz}{z^2+z}=\int_0^{2\pi}\mathrm d\theta + \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{iRe^{i\theta}}{Re^{i\theta}+1} \mathrm d\theta$. How would you then evaluate the second integral?

Answer (score 0):

These integrals are related to the [Poisson kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_kernel). If $R>1$ we have
$$ \frac{1}{R+e^{i\theta}} = \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n e^{ni\theta}}{R^{n+1}},\qquad \frac{1}{R+e^{-i\theta}} = \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n e^{-ni\theta}}{R^{n+1}} $$
hence by considering the sum/difference/product between these representations, and the fact that $\int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{ki\theta}\,d\theta = 2\pi \delta(k)$, the computation of the given integrals is straightforward. If $R\in(0,1)$ one may apply the same principle to
$$ \frac{1}{R+e^{i\theta}} = \sum_{n\geq 0}(-1)^n R^n e^{-(n+1)i\theta},\qquad \frac{1}{R+e^{-i\theta}} = \sum_{n\geq 0}(-1)^n R^n e^{(n+1)i\theta}$$
and if $R=1$ one may tackle the given integrals through the tangent half-angle substitution.